# Customize button run 2 times click event in one single Mouse click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a customize button that inherited Button class in winform application, and set mouse Event as below

```
private void _MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        MState = MouseState.Down;
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void _MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        MState = MouseState.Up;
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void _MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        MState = MouseState.Move;
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void _MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MState = MouseState.Leave;
        Invalidate();
    }
```

and in Constructor I set

```
        this.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(_MouseLeave);
        this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(_MouseDown);
        this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(_MouseUp);
        this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(_MouseMove);
```

But when i implement this button in the form and set Click Event, everytime user click button, it runs Click Event 2 times and in my case 2 record have been inserted into database. I don't know what i was missing , can you help out. Many thanks

Comment: where is the code that persists to DB?

Comment: Why u need to have mouse events and where you are sending data to DB?

Comment: Without any additional code my guess is that you inherited from button which has its own mouse events and you are adding your own so both are being fired.  Your mouse down and the base class mouseDown.  You need to override the native events and not add to them.  use the "protected override MouseDown() to override them and add your additional code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to all of you for the good answer, but by the simple code add to the _MouseDown event my problem is blown up

```
private void _MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        MState = MouseState.Down;
        (sender as Button).Enabled = false;
        (sender as Button).Enabled = true;
        (sender as Button).Refresh();
        Invalidate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you click the mouse, Mouse Down is fired and then Mouse Up when you release the click.

Comment: But what happens with Click event, all them are different

Comment: Where is the click event? your code doesn't show that. Why are you overriding the mouse events?

Answer (score 0):

The `MouseDown` event of any control is triggered as soon as you click the control,no matter if it's right click/Left click.Although you can target specific moue buttons if you use events such as `MouseLeftButtonDown`

The `MouseUp` event fires when you release a control from `MouseDown` or should i say mouse click.The problem is you are calling the same method/Function(Don't know what `Invalidate` is) on both the `MouseUp` and `MouseDown` event.I hope you understand the issue :)

Comment: Invalidate is a base function in Control class and Invalidates the entire surface of the control and causes the control to be redrawn. I want my button to be redraw to have a new color
 Public void Invalidate ()

Comment: Whatever it is,i hope after reading my answer,u understood ur mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional code my guess is that you inherited from button which has its own mouse events and you are adding your own so both are being fired. Your MouseDown and the base class MouseDown. You need to override the native events and not add to them. use the protected override MouseDown() to override them and add your additional code